# SHEETJS to JSON -- How to fix badly formatted JSON

Tags: javascript, json, excel, sheetjs

Using SheetJS, I am transferring an excel document into a JSON to interact with.
The problem is the Excel Documents I will be using for this are in an odd format. see pic
[IMG of Excel Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e707S.png)

When I transfer them from XLSX to JSON using SheetJS It does not connect my keys and values correctly.

```
{ __EMPTY: 'Lagoon 03', __EMPTY_2: 'Pools' },
  { __EMPTY: 'Height', __EMPTY_2: '2"' },
  { __EMPTY: 'Depth', __EMPTY_2: `3' 6" - 5' - 4'` },
  { __EMPTY: 'Perimeter', __EMPTY_2: `76' 5"` },
  { __EMPTY: 'Area', __EMPTY_2: '381.41 ft²' },
  { __EMPTY: 'Interior Area', __EMPTY_2: '699.94 ft²' },
  { __EMPTY: 'Materials' },
  { __EMPTY: 'Aqua', __EMPTY_2: 'Pool Interiors', __EMPTY_3: 'Quartz' },
  {
    __EMPTY: 'Stone, Blue Beach',
    __EMPTY_2: 'Tile',
    __EMPTY_3: '6x6"'
  },
```

Does anyone know how to fix this __EMPTY problem? For instant with the code above what I'm looking for is. 
Lagoon 03 as the main KEY and subkeys for height, perimeter, etc.

Thanks in advance for anyone that can help me with this

Answer (score 0):

```js
var src = [{ __EMPTY: 'Lagoon 03', __EMPTY_2: 'Pools' },
    { __EMPTY: 'Height', __EMPTY_2: '2"' },
    { __EMPTY: 'Depth', __EMPTY_2: '3\' 6" - 5\' - 4\'' },
    { __EMPTY: 'Perimeter', __EMPTY_2: '76\' 5"' },
    { __EMPTY: 'Area', __EMPTY_2: '381.41 ft²' },
    { __EMPTY: 'Interior Area', __EMPTY_2: '699.94 ft²' },
    { __EMPTY: 'Materials' },
    { __EMPTY: 'Aqua', __EMPTY_2: 'Pool Interiors', __EMPTY_3: 'Quartz' },
    {
        __EMPTY: 'Stone, Blue Beach',
        __EMPTY_2: 'Tile',
        __EMPTY_3: '6x6"'
    }
];
console.log(src[0].__EMPTY);
console.log(src[1]['__EMPTY_2']);
console.log(src[3].__EMPTY_2);
```

Or using my JSON Iterator you can traverse or find some value(s) like this...

```js
var src = [{ __EMPTY: 'Lagoon 03', __EMPTY_2: 'Pools' },
    { __EMPTY: 'Height', __EMPTY_2: '2"' },
    { __EMPTY: 'Depth', __EMPTY_2: '3\' 6" - 5\' - 4\'' },
    { __EMPTY: 'Perimeter', __EMPTY_2: '76\' 5"' },
    { __EMPTY: 'Area', __EMPTY_2: '381.41 ft²' },
    { __EMPTY: 'Interior Area', __EMPTY_2: '699.94 ft²' },
    { __EMPTY: 'Materials' },
    { __EMPTY: 'Aqua', __EMPTY_2: 'Pool Interiors', __EMPTY_3: 'Quartz' },
    {
        __EMPTY: 'Stone, Blue Beach',
        __EMPTY_2: 'Tile',
        __EMPTY_3: '6x6"'
    }
];
function demoTraverse (json) {
    var it = new JIterator(json);
    var looking4 = ['Lagoon 03', 'Height', 'Perimeter', 'Pools'];
    var frst = looking4.pop();
    console.log(frst, '>', it.FindValue(frst).pred.value);
    for (var val of looking4) {
        var item = it.FindValue(val);
        if (item) { console.log(item.key, item.next.value, '<', item.value); }
    }
    do {
        if (it.Current.HasOwnKey) console.log(it.Current.key, it.Current.value);
    } while (it.DepthFirst());
}

'use strict';
var JNode = (function (jsNode) {
    function JNode (_json, _parent, _pred, _key, _value) {
        this.parent = _parent;
        this.pred = _pred;
        this.node = null;
        this.next = null;
        this.key = _key;
        this.value = _value;
        this.json = _json;
    }
    JNode.prototype = {
        get HasOwnKey () { return this.key && (this.key.constructor !== Number); },
        get HasStringValue () { return this.value.constructor === String; }
    };
    return JNode;
})();
var JIterator = (function (json) {
    var JNodePrivates = (function (parent) {
        function JNodePrivates () {
            this.root = null;
            this.current = null;
        }
        JNodePrivates.prototype = {
            get Root () {
                return this.root;
            },
            setRoot: function (newRoot) {
                return (this.root = newRoot);
            },
            get Current () {
                return this.current;
            },
            setCurrent: function (newCurrent) {
                return (this.current = newCurrent);
            }
        };
        return JNodePrivates;
    })();
    var maxLevel = -1;
    function JIterator (json, parent) {
        if (this._privates === undefined) this._privates = new JNodePrivates();
        if (parent === undefined) parent = null;
        var pred = null; var localCurrent;
        for (var child in json) {
            var obj = json[child] instanceof Object;
            if (json instanceof Array) child = parseInt(child); // non-associative array
            if (!this._privates.Root) this._privates.setRoot(localCurrent = new JNode(json, parent, null, child, json[child]));
            else {
                localCurrent = new JNode(json[child], parent, pred, child, obj ? ((json[child] instanceof Array) ? [] : {}) : json[child]);
            }
            if (pred) pred.next = localCurrent;
            if (parent && parent.node == null) parent.node = localCurrent;
            pred = localCurrent;
            if (obj) {
                var memPred = pred;
                JIterator.call(this, json[child], pred);
                pred = memPred;
            }
        }
        if (!this._privates.Current && this._privates.Root) this._privates.setCurrent(this._privates.Root);
    }
    JIterator.prototype = {
        // Public Getters
        get Current () { return this._privates.Current; },
        SetCurrent: function (newCurrent) { return this._privates.setCurrent(newCurrent); },
        get Path () {
            var steps = []; var level = this._privates.Current;
            do {
                if (level != null && level.value instanceof Object) {
                    if (level.value instanceof Array) {
                        if (steps.length > 0) {
                            steps.push(level.key + '[' + steps.pop() + ']');
                        } else {
                            steps.push(level.key);
                        }
                    } else {
                        steps.push(level.key);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (level != null) steps.push(level.key);
                    else break;
                }
                level = level.parent;
            } while (level != null);
            steps.forEach(function (el, i) {
                if (!isNaN(el)) steps[i] = '[' + el + ']';
            });
            return steps.reverse().join('.');
        },
        // Public Setters
        set current (value) {
            console.log('Use SetCurrent(' + value + ') !');
            throw 'Access to current Denied !';
        },
        // Public methods
        Parent: function () {
            var retVal = this._privates.Current.parent;
            if (retVal == null) return false;
            this.Level--;
            return this._privates.setCurrent(retVal);
        },
        Pred: function () {
            var retVal = this._privates.Current.pred;
            if (retVal == null) return false;
            return this._privates.setCurrent(retVal);
        },
        Node: function () {
            var retVal = this._privates.Current.node;
            if (retVal == null) return false;
            this.Level++;
            return this._privates.setCurrent(retVal);
        },
        Next: function () {
            var retVal = this._privates.Current.next;
            if (retVal == null) return false;
            return this._privates.setCurrent(retVal);
        },
        get Key () {
            if (this._privates.Current) return this._privates.Current.key;
            return undefined;
        },
        KeyDots: function () { return (!this.HasOwnKey) ? '' : (this._privates.Current.key + ':'); },
        get Value () {
            if (this._privates.Current) return this._privates.Current.value;
            return undefined;
        },
        Reset: function () {
            this._privates.setCurrent(this._privates.Root);
            this.Level = 0;
        },
        RawPath: function () {
            var steps = []; var level = this._privates.Current;
            do {
                if (level != null && level.value instanceof Object) {
                    steps.push(level.key + (level.value instanceof Array ? '[]' : '{}'));
                } else {
                    if (level != null) steps.push(level.key);
                    else break;
                }
                level = level.parent;
            } while (level != null);
            var retVal = '';
            retVal = steps.reverse();
            return retVal;
        },
        DepthFirst: function () {
            if (this._privates.Current == null) return 0; // exit sign
            if (this._privates.Current.node != null) {
                this._privates.setCurrent(this._privates.Current.node);
                this.Level++;
                if (maxLevel < this.Level) maxLevel = this.Level;
                return 1; // moved down
            } else if (this._privates.Current.next != null) {
                this._privates.setCurrent(this._privates.Current.next);
                return 2; // moved right
            } else {
                while (this._privates.Current != null) {
                    if (this._privates.Current.next != null) {
                        this._privates.setCurrent(this._privates.Current.next);
                        return 3; // returned up & moved next
                    }
                    this.Level--;
                    this._privates.setCurrent(this._privates.Current.parent);
                }
            }
            return 0; // exit sign
        },
        BreadthFirst: function () {
            if (this._privates.Current == null) return 0; // exit sign
            if (this._privates.Current.next) {
                this._privates.setCurrent(this._privates.Current.next);
                return 1; // moved right
            } else if (this._privates.Current.parent) {
                var level = this.Level;
                while (this.DepthFirst() && level !== this.Level);
                if (this._privates.Current) return 2; // returned up & moved next
                do {
                    this.Reset();
                    level++;
                    while (this.DepthFirst() && level !== this.Level);
                    if (this._privates.Current) return 3; // returned up & moved next
                } while (maxLevel >= level);
                return this._privates.Current != null ? 3 : 0;
            } else if (this._privates.Current.node) {
                this._privates.setCurrent(this._privates.Current.node);
                return 3;
            } else if (this._privates.Current.pred) {
                while (this._privates.Current.pred) this._privates.setCurrent(this._privates.Current.pred);
                while (this._privates.Current && !this._privates.Current.node) this._privates.setCurrent(this._privates.Current.next);
                if (!this._privates.Current) return null;
                else return this.DepthFirst();
            }
        },
        ReadArray: function () {
            var retVal = {};
            var item = this._privates.Current;
            do {
                if (item.value instanceof Object) {
                    if (item.value.length === 0) retVal[item.key] = item.node;
                    else retVal[item.key] = item;
                } else retVal[item.key] = item.value;
                item = item.next;
            } while (item != null);
            return retVal;
        },
        FindKey: function (key) {
            var pos = this._privates.Current;
            while (this._privates.Current && this._privates.Current.key !== key) this.DepthFirst();
            if (this._privates.Current.key === key) {
                var retVal = this._privates.Current;
                this._privates.setCurrent(pos);
                return retVal;
            } else {
                this._privates.setCurrent(pos);
                return null;
            }
        },
        FindValue: function (val) {
            var pos = this._privates.Current;
            while (this._privates.Current && this._privates.Current.value !== val) this.DepthFirst();
            if (this._privates.Current.value === val) {
                var retVal = this._privates.Current;
                this._privates.setCurrent(pos);
                return retVal;
            } else {
                this._privates.setCurrent(pos);
                return null;
            }
        },
        FindPair: function (key, value, move2) {
            var pos = this._privates.current;
            while (this._privates.current) {
                if (this._privates.current.key === key && this._privates.current.value === value) {
                    break;
                } else this.DepthFirst();
            }
            if (move2) return this._privates.current;
            var retVal = this._privates.current;
            this.SetCurrent(pos);
            return retVal;
        },
        // Debug info methods
        PathDetails: function (brief) {
            var steps = []; var level = this._privates.Current;
            do {
                if (level != null && level.value instanceof Object) {
                    var size = 0;
                    var items = level.node;
                    if (!level.HasOwnKey && !brief) steps.push('[' + level.key + ']');
                    else {
                        if (brief) {
                            if (level.HasOwnKey) steps.push(level.key);
                        } else {
                            while (items) {
                                size++;
                                items = items.next;
                            }
                            var type = (level.value instanceof Array ? '[]' : '{}');
                            var prev = steps[steps.length - 1];
                            if (prev && prev[0] === '[') {
                                var last = prev.length - 1;
                                if (prev[last] === ']') {
                                    last--;
                                    if (!isNaN(prev.substr(1, last))) {
                                        steps.pop();
                                        size += '.' + prev.substr(1, last);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            steps.push(level.key + type[0] + size + type[1]);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (level != null) {
                        if (!level.HasOwnKey) steps.push('[' + level.key + ']');
                        else steps.push(level.key);
                    } else break;
                }
                level = level.parent;
            } while (level != null);
            var retVal = '';
            retVal = steps.reverse();
            return retVal;
        },
        Move2path: function (json) {
            var nd = this._privates.current;
            var pth = [nd];
            while (nd.parent) {
                nd = nd.parent;
                pth.push(nd);
            }
            pth.reverse();
            for (var x in pth) json = json[pth[x].key];
            return json;
        },
        CreateNode: function (json, key, value) {
            var current = this._privates.Current;
            if (current) {
                current.node = new JNode(json, current, current.pred, key, value);
                if (isNaN(key)) json[key] = value;
                return current.node;
            } else {
                current = new JNode(json, null, null, key, value);
                json[key] = value;
                this._privates.setCurrent(current);
                this._privates.setRoot(current);
                return current;
            }
        }
    };
    return JIterator;
})();

demoTraverse(src);
```